# Multiple Listener on same port and private ip in applicationgateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

Can we have multiple listeners on the same frontend Private ip and same port in application gateway?

I was in a process of designing a solution with internal AppGw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple listeners on the same frontend Private Ip but Application Gateway V2 currently does not support only private IP address.

[image]

If you want to use [Application Gateway V2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-front-end-ip) with only private IP Create with both public and private frontend IP address and ***create a listener with the private Frontend IP and leave the Public IP as such.***

For [listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-listeners) Azure does not support to create a public and private listener on the same port.

For more information in detail, please check this below ***reference***:

[How do I use Application Gateway V2 with only private frontend IP address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq#can-i-use-the-same-port-for-both-public-facing-and-private-facing-listeners)

[Error when creating listener on Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/452279/error-when-creating-listener-on-application-gatewa.html)

Comment: Yup was thinking the same thing , will create a NSG to block any incoming and outgoing traffic to the public ip .Thanks